# Windows Installer XML (WiX) templates

Tags: xml, windows, templates, wix, installation

I want to use WiX for building an install for a software.
I have downloaded the last version WiX toolset and have seen the installer of the toolset. 
It looks really good (Window Tiles with animations and Icons) and I was wondering if this one has been built with WiX itself too? And is it possible to find a website with cool templates to be used?

Unfortunately every search in the internet combined with WiX and templates takes me to the Wix Websites building templates.

Comment: First question: Yes, and you can get the source code via the appropriate download (e.g., wix310-debug.zip) on a release page. [3.10](https://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/619491).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, that installer is built with Wix, but the UI is WPF if I am not mistaken. The EXE installer is a boostrapper which controls the UI ad launches the MSI installation silently in the background.

This is a very detailed article on how to write your own custom bootstrapper:

https://www.wrightfully.com/part-1-of-writing-your-own-net-based-installer-with-wix-overview/

The thing is that from my knowledge you will never find such templates for download. Usually they are custom designed for a certain installer and when you work so much on a design you don't want to make it easy for others to copy it.

**If you are looking for building an installer fast and easy, but also reliable**, you need to start looking at commercial software, like our tool Advanced Installer or the rest.

I know you will say the price for the Enterprise edition (*the one which includes a drag and drop Dialogs Editor*) is not small, but you must also remember that your time spent on manually writing the installer in Wix and .NET also costs a lot, in many cases much more than you pay for a license (*P.S. I think that's why we're all using Windows, not Linux, isn't it? Anyway this is another subject, it's better not to get into it.*)

Here are a few screenshots with some templates from Advanced Installer:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Up to a point, your answer provides the rational for a different approach. But, the screen shots go well beyond that. They also don't address the question of templates.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Tom. I added links to the screenshots just to show how one commercial tool (Advanced Installer in this case) provides these templates by default, with just one click (these are not custom built). Do you think they pollute the answer? (we can always remove some of them and just leave one as a sample)